# UTC timestamp format for launch vehicles

Tags: time

Has anyone ever seen UTC timestamps of the format xxx:HH:mm:ss.sss? What are the three x's at the front. For reference, this timestamp belongs to an upcoming launch in June of 2019.

[image]

Comment: I think it would be best if you shared a link to your example, or a screen shot. It doesn't make sense to me. See [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/36633/12102) for example.

Comment: Upcoming (or perhaps past) launch of **what** vehicle? A link would be a very good thing. I am downvoting for three reasons. One, I do not like images that do not have an explanatory alt text. It's important to remember that an image is worth a thousand words (of alt text).Two, no link. Three, the very vague "upcoming launch in June of 2019".

Comment: @DavidHammen: Even worse, it is an image *of text*, which is the absolute most worthless kind of image there is. Not only is it completely useless for visually impaired readers, it doesn't even add any additional information for sighted readers.

Comment: Liftoff precisely at midnight (to the millisecond) UTC sounds like a strange coincidence too. Are you sure those are in fact UTC times rather than some sort of mission elapsed timescale?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the n-th **day of the year**, going from 1 to 365 (or 366).

So 006 would be January 6.

Comment: That was my first thought as well. The launch this is scheduled for is in June though and this prediction was made in March. I edited the question to add that.

Comment: There was no launch on 2019 January 6. The first launch in 2019 was on January 10.

Comment: It would be nice to know where the timestamp comes from. Could be a format error and displaying the month (June -> 6) instead of the day.

Comment: But in the question the timestamp 006 belonged to June 2019 .

Answer (score 6):

To confirm other answers that the leading three-digit number is day number for the year starting with 1 being 01-Jan:

Note the counter in the lower-left of the video [[ISS] Launch of Antares Rocket with Cygnus CRS-2 Spacecraft to ISS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vYYNc2_EqQY) is `194 16:52:14.xxx` at launch, corresponding to a [13 July 2014, 16:52:14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygnus_CRS_Orb-2) launch time, with 13-July-2014 being the [194th day of 2014](https://www.calendar-365.com/day-numbers/2014.html)

If you are seeing a *three digit* `006` *immediately before hours* for a launch in June, then something is strange.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

days:hours:minutes:seconds.fractions_of_seconds